# Android: Call MapActivity Mapquest from Activity class

Tags: android, android-intent, mapactivity, start-activity, mapquest

Friends!

I can't call `MapActivity` from other activity :

```
Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapScreen.class); 
startActivity(nextScreen);
```

Where `MapScreen.class` is a `public class MapScreen extends MapActivity`

the error message is:

```
03-20 11:00:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(31450): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 11:00:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(31450): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.router.android/com.router.android.MapScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 11:00:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(31450): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2081)
03-20 11:00:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(31450): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
03-20 11:00:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(31450): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
03-20 11:00:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(31450): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1217)
03-20 11:00:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(31450): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 11:00:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(31450): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 11:00:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(31450): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
03-20 11:00:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(31450): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 11:00:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(31450): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-20 11:00:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(31450): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
```

Comment: if you start your app with MapActivity it really works?

Comment: Yes... works :D and with other activity works but the problem is with MapScreen extends MapActivity of mapquest library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open MapScreen class from another activity is correct with

```
Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapScreen.class); 
startActivity(nextScreen);
```

or

```
Intent nextScreen = new Intent(this, MapScreen.class); 
startActivity(nextScreen);
```

I think the problem is in your MapScreen class, must have a `onCreate()` method.

```
public class MapScreen extends MapActivity{

protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
```

like this example class:
http://depaul-android-app.googlecode.com/svn/tags/0.0.1/src/edu/depaul/android/activities/MapScreen.java

Comment: I think that it works for googlemaps for mapquest... because continue the same error message... 

**public class MapScreen extends MapActivity {**
 @Override
 public  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);